# collect and format logs from stdout(php - monolog) in node js with exec

Tags: php, node.js, monolog, bunyan

my PHP call from node.js is :

```
const process = exec('php ' + phpScriptPath, (err, phpResponse, stderr) => {

            if (err){
                this.logger.error('failed:' , err);
            }
        });

        process.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
            this.logger.info(data.toString());
        });
```

I am sending the logs  from the PHP script using monolog like following

the logs look like the following :

```
{"name":"node","environment":"development","hostname":"local","level":50,"msg":"{\"message\":\"log message\",\"context\":{\"error\":\"error message\"},\"level\":400,\"level_name\":\"ERROR\",\"extra\":[]}\n","time":"2019-05-05T06:38:26.147Z","v":0}
```

using Bunyan ,
how can I format this message to be more readable

PHP monolog formatter :

```
 $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\JsonFormatter();
        $streamHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
        $streamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);
        $log->pushHandler($streamHandler);
```

2- Php has a diffrent level of logs, how can I check what is the level of logs in node, hoe can I format the message in stdout and get the log level.

`\"level_name\":\"ERROR\`" .  for example
so I will find the "ERROR" string

3- How can I fit between the log level in node and php.
 if my node log level is "error", I won't be able to print the stdout logs because my code is. `"this.logger.error()"` . I need something more dynamic then hardcoded logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok for my second question I found the solution: if I get PHP log as  a JSON string I just can use the following from stdout:

```
 var phplog = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(phplog.level_name)
// will print ERROR
```